# Rails - adding a string in front of a form parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am at a lost and cannot seem to find a solution anywhere for this...

all i want to do is be able to add a little greeting in front of my user's name when they submit a form via an external API...so nothing is being saved to my database

ALL I WANT TO BE ABLE TO DO IS THIS

```
 "Web inquiry from Jon Doe"
```

so i have a form

```
  <%= text_field :subject %>
```

when the user puts his name into it and submits the form my client can go to the external website where its being posted and see

```
 "Web inquiry from Jon Doe"
```

So i just need to be able to tack on the

```
 Web inquiry from
```

part to the name on the form?

Please help me...your my only hope

heres my controller

```
class Website::ContactsController < Website::WebsiteApplicationController
  def new
    @contacts = Form.new
  end

  def create
    @contacts = Form.new(params[:contacts])
    @contacts.post_tickets(params[:contacts])
    if @contacts.valid?
      flash[:success] = "Message sent! Thank you for conacting us."
      redirect_to new_contact_path
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Please fill in the required fields"
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

heres my form

```
 = form_for(:contacts, url: contacts_path) do |f| 
   = f.error_messages
   = f.label :subject, "Name"
   %span{style: 'color: red'} *
   = f.text_field :subject, class: "text_field width_100_percent"
    %br
    %br    
    = f.label "Email"
    %span{style: 'color: red'} *
    %br    
    = f.email_field :email, class: "text_field width_100_percent"
    %br
    %br
    = f.label "Phone"
    %br    
    = f.text_field :custom_field_phone_number_28445, name: 'contacts[custom_field][phone_number_28445]', class: "text_field width_100_percent"
    %br
    %br
    = f.label "Company"
    %br    
    = f.text_field :custom_field_company_28445, name: 'contacts[custom_field][company_28445]', class: "text_field width_100_percent"
    %br
    %br
    = f.label "Question(s), and/or feedback"
    %span{style: 'color: red'} *
    %br
    = f.text_area :description, class: "text_field width_100_percent", style: 'height: 100px;'
    %br
    %br
    = f.submit "Submit", class: 'btn btn-warning'
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this suffice?

```
message = "Web inquiry from " + params[:subject]
```

Comment: im sorry im new to rails....how would i use this?  would i put it in the controller or the modeL?

Comment: Probably in the view where this is being displayed.

Comment: = f.text_field :subject, message = "Web inquiry from " + params[:subject].....like that?

Comment: i get a can't convert nil into String

Comment: Do you want the "Web inquiry from" part to be pre-populated? Or are you appending that after the fact? Your question suggests it's added later when it's displayed, in which case this goes into the associated view where this record is rendered, not the form where you're creating it in the first place.